# Nested for loop with list parallelization in OpenMP

Tags: c, list, for-loop, openmp

Is there any way to parallelize the following code without having the overhead of copying the list to an array?
I've already tried the following and it doesn't work because of list parallelization. Do I need a critical region on the list?

```
Node* it;
int x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for private(x,y,it)
for(x=0; x<cube_size;x++){
    for(y=0; y<cube_size; y++){
        for(it = *(graph1[x][y]); it != NULL; it = it->next){
           if(it->status == ALIVE){
               if(it->counter < 2 || it->counter > 4){
                 it->status = DEAD;
               }
           }else{
              if(it->counter == 2 || it->counter == 3){
                 it->status = ALIVE;
              }
           }
           it->counter = 0;                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to tell us more about the layout of those lists. Are those independant lists for each `graph1` entry? Preferably, post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, they are independent lists for each graph1 entry. The example is hard because there is quite a lot more code than only this

Comment: Yes, writing a good question is hard, but necessary to get a good answer. For instance you are even lacking any kind of description what you mean by *"it doesn't work"*.

Comment: You are right. I meant that there is no speedup at all. Is the logic of parallelizing the outer loop correct of this (private iterator)?

Comment: We can't properly discuss performance issues without specific performance numbers including a clear description on how you measured these as well as a system description and eventually a [mcve].

Comment: Alright, I'll put it here :)

Comment: I don't understand the code structure. Please put a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example